# Android Crash - how to debug this?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm getting intermittent crashes in an Android app running on a physical device.   The app has several screens with buttons and a ListView.  It has two threads -  the main UI thread and a worker thread that receives information over WiFi.  The worker thread never directly touches any UI components.  When it gets information over WiFi it uses a *runOnUiThread* to call a routine that writes to an ArrayList that will be read by the UI.

In the past when I got a crash I could look in the stack trace in the Debug tab of the Debug Perspective and I find some of my own code and that was a good clue where my bug was, but this stack dump has **nothing** of mine - it's all internal.   Furthermore, it just says "Runtime Exception", not what the exception actually IS . . .

> Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))
>     ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord,
>     ActivityThread$StopInfo, boolean) line: 2434
>     ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(IBinder, boolean, int) line: 2479 
>     ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread, IBinder, boolean, int)
>   line: 117     BinderProxy(ActivityThread$H).handleMessage(Message) line:
>   952       ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
>     Looper.loop() line: 130     ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3687
>     Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int,
>   boolean) line: not available [native method]      Method.invoke(Object,
>   Object...) line: 507      ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 842
>     ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 600     NativeStart.main(String[])
>   line: not available [native method]
>
> Thread [<8> Binder Thread #2] (Running)
>
> Thread [<7> Binder Thread #1] (Running)
>
> Thread [<9>> Thread-10] (Running)
>
> Thread [<10> Binder Thread #3] (Running)

Another factor: The crash happens sporadically, and there's no specific sequence to reproduce it - it has to be doing SOMETHING -  pressing a button or receiving data - it won't crash just sitting on a table doing nothing - but it's not always the same thing to reproduce it.

How do I figure out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This line gives me a hunch:

`Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available`

The fact that it's coming out of the native API suggests that it may be an API version problem.  Check your problems view (if you're using Eclipse) and grep your code for `@SuppressLint` annotations and make sure you're not ignoring or suppressing any "new API" or "inlined API" compiler warnings.

Comment: That was a good idea, but no, no warnings are being suppressed and no API messages are being generated.